# BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer isn't visible from the Internet

Tags: python, http

I'm running a Python server on a remote server:

```
    server_class = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
    httpd = server_class(("127.0.0.1", 80), MyHandler)
    httpd.serve_forever()        
    httpd.server_close()
```

From a server, I can make a query: "curl -i localhost" and it works fine. However, from a remote computer I can't, even though there's no firewall.

```
  curl: (7) Failed to connect to aa.bb.cc.dd port 80: Connection refused
```

I'm trying to do that by the ip address of a server.

Comment: Is port 80 opened in the firewall of the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you cannot. You bind you server to the 127.0.0.1 local only address, so it can only answer local queries. Use the special `0.0.0.0` address to allow it to answer on any interfaces:

```
httpd = server_class(("0.0.0.0", 80), MyHandler)
```